# How to save specAugment warped melspectrogram as a Wav file

Tags: python, tensorflow, librosa, data-augmentation

I am trying to implement a github repo specAugment (https://github.com/DemisEom/SpecAugment)

After loading the wav file using librosa, I believe it uses numPy reshape function to reshape the melspectrogram array, get Log scale melspectrogram by using power_to_db function and apply the data augmentation.

My question is, is it possible to get a wav file of the augmented data ? If so, how ? I would appreciate any pointers or even just the steps needed to convert the results back to a wav file.

I tried librosa's inverse.mel_to_audio() function but to no avail. I also tried scipy.io.wavfile.write()

Answer (score 0):

from what I know, the process of converting a spectrogram back to a waveform is not a trivial task.

Librosa does support the method as you mentioned and it's using the Griffin-Lim algorithm, which is one of the basic and most convenient if you want an instant-noodle trial. At this point I don't know what specific problem you are encountering, you may need to provide more details here.

On top of this, nowadays, people are focusing on developing deep learning models for this task as they significantly generate much higher quality audio from spectrogram - WaveNet, WaveGlow, ParallelWaveGAN, etc. to name a few, as they play an important role in Text-to-speech systems.